# Limpar o cache do meu usuário?

Tags: navegador-de-internet, cache

Eu peguei uma loja virtual pra fazer alguns updates, e até ai tudo bem. Fiz, etc...

O problema é o seguinte. As modificações de CSS só são aplicadas no navegador dos clientes, se eles limparem o histórico do navegador deles. Se por exemplo, eles entraram uma semana antes no site, e hoje, depois da atualização que eu fiz, eles entrarem de novo, o site vai ficar ainda com aquelas informações de CSS da ultima vez que o site dele "baixou o meu site".

Como a loja é Magento, tem as opções para limpar cache, e tem também a parte de limpar cache CDN, mas não adianta.

Existe alguma coisa em PHP ou JavaScript que faça ele apagar esses dados do navegador do cliente?

Comment: Com PHP é impossível. Não sei se existe algo em JS pra fazer algo assim. De qualquer forma, a melhor ideia é "versionar" o arquivo CSS e sempre  usar um nome diferente nele, isso vai fazer com que o browser seja obrigado a baixá-lo.

Comment: Gostei dessa solução, de versionar, obrigado LINQ!

Comment: Não precisa renomear o arquivo, basta passar uma querystring pra ele, por exemplo `script.js?v=123`.

Comment: Como disse o amigo @bfavaretto, vc pode tb adicionar uma querystring dinâmica sempre atualizada com `echo`: `meu_css.css?<?php echo date("ymdHis"); ?>`, com ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto e segundos.

Comment: Não tem como um código via HTML fazer esse tipo de intervenção na máquina do cliente. Ou vc cria mecanismos para "enganar" o navegador (como as sugestões nos outros comentários) ou então pede pro usuário acessar as configurações do navegador e limpar o cache (não recomendado).